# ASIFormDataRequest : image post to .net service

Tags: iphone, asp.net

i want to post image from iphone/ipad to .net service.Currently i am using ASIFormDataRequest but i am getting error

> "Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8;
>   boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY."

please help me to solve this error.
Thank you

Comment: Give a try to my approach, or if you get it working with ASI please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set data in your `ASIFormDataRequest` like this

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
[request addData:imgData withFileName:@"FILENAME" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:@"YOUR KEY"];
```

Where request is your `ASIFormDataRequest`

Happy coding.

Comment: i have added this code but what i have to configure at server side

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)uploadFile{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: photoUploadURLString];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    //if you have your site secured by .htaccess

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipodfile%@.jpg",self.fileID];//your image file name
    [request addPostValue:fileName forKey:@"name"];

    // Upload an image
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageName:fileName]) // your image 
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{    
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog("Upload response %@", responseString);
}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

    NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]); 
 }
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is with the web service. I'm not sure what type of data I should be receiving from the app POST.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: then how can we help if u don't know type of data u should be recieving.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem.. Same error..

But i resolved it in some different apporach.

Basically .Net webservice expects the image to be supplied as `binary` or `byte[]` array.

There is no way i found to send an `UIImage` as `byte[]` using `ASIFormDataRequest` to the server.

But `NSURLRequest` does it in a better way, We need to dig bit more than the usual.

I had a gud experience in working with `Sudzc` soap framework for iOS,  This is not open source, but you can get it for free.

All you need to do is,

1. you need the WSDL link, you can get it like, if
   ***http://.....xyz.asmx*** is your base URL, then, ***http://.....xyz.asmx/wsdl*** will give you the WSDL, you can check it in browser.
2. visit [www.sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com)
3. paste the URL, select ***Objectivc-C for iOS*** project from the
   dropdown list below the URL field. you can give the prefix if you need or you can avoid that.
4. click **Generate**

This will get you a zip file, which has the iOS project. once you open up the project, check the `Generated` directory you can see all you need.